# Conver Vector datatype "probability" column in the dataset<row> predictions to Array?

Tags: java, apache-spark, vector, dataset

I have a dataset as follows:

```
 Dataset<Row> result =   result.select("Probability","label","prediction");
```

The DataType of Probability is `Vector`, and I want to convert it to `Array` so that the dataset can be saved to a database. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a similar issue and I solved writing a custom UDF which extracts an element from the Vector and returns it as a double:

```java
static UDF2<Vector, Integer, Double> probability_at = (UDF2<Vector, Integer, Double>) Vector::apply;
```

To use the UDF you first need to register it in the `SparkSession`:

```java
spark.udf().register("probability_at", probability_at, DoubleType);
```

and you can use it:

```java
Dataset<Row> result = df.select(col("label"), col("prediction"), expr("probability_at(Probability, 1)").as("probability_1"));
```

At this point you have a new column `probability_1` in the `result` DataFrame that contains the element in position 1 of the Probability Vector, as a double.

You can call the function multiple times if you need to extract multiple items from the Vector or you can create a similiar UDF that loops over the entire Vector and returns an array of double.